# What will be complexity in this Balanced BST?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, red-black-tree

I have been asked this question in an interview and I'm curious to know what will be the correct explanation for it?

> Consider the following height balanced BST where `Balance factor = Height of left subtree - Height of right subtree` & the accepted balance factors are 0, 1, -1, 2, and -2.
> What will be the time taken to search an element in such a kind of height-balanced BST? Explain.

What I said was, even if it has a height factor of `2` rather than `1` in standard Balance BST definitions, still the operations should be `logN` complexity order, (where N is the number of elements in the tree) because when the N will be large then will be not making much difference if the height factor is 2 or 1.

If anyone can tell me what would have been the correct answer here will be helpful :)

Comment: Well, I would say time taken is not entirely the same as the complexity. But you are right in saying that searching operation will be still logN in **large enough** tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve this **mathematically** as :

### **Defining Worst Case**

Now, in any `Binary Tree`, time complexity of `searching` is  `O(h)` where `h` is ***height*** of the `Binary Tree`.
Now, for worst case, we want to find ***Maximum Height.***

> In case of simple `Binary Search Tree` with no Balancing Factor
> Condition on Nodes, this maximum height can be `n` or `n+1` *(depending
> on convention whether height of single node tree will be 1 or 0)*
> where `n` is number of nodes.

Thus, we can say that `given number of nodes, worst case is maximum height`.

Interestingly, we can also say that `given height of a tree, the worst case is minimum nodes`. As even for such minimum number of nodes, we might have to traverse down the tree of height `h`, which we also have to do for maximum number of nodes.

Thus, the intuition should be clear that `Given Height of Tree, the worst case is minimum number of nodes.`

### **Applying this Concept on Binary Search Tree**

1. Let us try to construct **Binary Search Tree** of Height `H` such that **number of nodes** in the tree is **minimum**.

> Here we will exploit the fact that Binary Tree is a Recursive Data
> Structure (A Binary Tree can be defined in terms of Binary Tree)

2. We will use the notation **N<sub>H</sub>** to denote Minimum Number of Nodes in a **Binary Search Tree** of height **H**
3. We will create a **Root Node**
   [image: Root Node]
4. To **Left** (or Right) of Root, add a **subtree** of height `H-1` (exploiting Recursive Property). So that number of nodes in entire tree is minimum, the number of node in **Left** (or Right) **subtree** should also be minimum. Thus **N<sub>H</sub>** is a function of
   **N<sub>H-1</sub>**
5. Do we need to add anything to **Right** (or Left)?
   No. *Because there is no restriction of Balancing Factor on BST. Thus, our tree will look like*
   [image]
6. Thus, to construct **Binary Search Tree** of Height `H` such that **number of nodes** in the tree is **minimum**, we can take **Binary Search Tree** of Height `H-1` such that **number of nodes** is
   **minimum**, and can add 1 root node.
   Thus, we can form `Recurrence Relation` as
   **N<sub>H</sub> = N<sub>H-1</sub> + 1**
   with base condition as
   **N<sub>0</sub>=1**

> To create BST of height 0, we need to add one node. Throughout the answer we will use this convention

7. Now, this `Recurrence Relation` is quite simple to solve by Substitution and thus
   **N<sub>H</sub> = H+1**
   N<sub>H</sub> > H
8. Now, let `n` be the number of nodes in the BST of height H
   Then,
   n ≥ N<sub>H</sub>
   n ≥ H
   H ≤ n
   Therefore,
   `H=O(n)`
   Or
   `O(H) = O(n)`

Thus, **Worst Case Time Complexity** for **Searching** will be `O(n)`

### **Applying this Concept on AVL Tree**

We can apply similar concept on AVL Tree. After reading later part of solution, one can find recurrence relation as :

> **N<sub>H</sub> = N<sub>H-1</sub> + N<sub>H-2</sub> + 1**

with Base Condition :

> **N<sub>0</sub> = 1**
>  **N<sub>1</sub> = 2**

And, inequality condition on solving recurrence will be

> **N<sub>H</sub> ≥ ((1+√5)/2)<sup>H</sup>**

Then, let `n` be the number of nodes. Thus,

> **n ≥ N<sub>H</sub>**

On simplifying, one can conclude that

> **H ≤ 1.44log<sub>2</sub>(n)**

### **Applying this Concept on GIVEN Tree**

1. Let us try to construct **Given Tree** of Height `H` such that **number of nodes** in the tree is **minimum**.
2. We will use the notation **N<sub>H</sub>** to denote Minimum Number of Nodes in **Given Tree** of height **H**
3. We will create a **Root Node**
   [image: Root Node]
4. To **Left** (or Right) of Root, add a **subtree** of height `H-1` (exploiting Recursive Property). So that number of nodes in entire tree is minimum, the number of node in **Left** (or Right) **subtree** should also be minimum. Thus **N<sub>H</sub>** is a function of
   **N<sub>H-1</sub>**
5. Do we need to add anything to **Right** (or Left)?
   Yes! *Because there is restriction of Balancing Factor on Nodes.*
   We need to add subtree on **Right** (or Left). **What should be it's height?**

   **H?**

   > No, then height of entire tree will become H+1

   **H-1?**

   > Permitted! since Balancing Factor of Root will be 0

   **H-2?**

   > Permitted! since Balancing Factor of Root will be 1

   **H-3?**

   > Permitted! since Balancing Factor of Root will be 2

   **H-4?**

   > Not Permitted! since Balancing Factor of Root will become 3

   We want minimum number of nodes, so out of `H-1`, `H-2` and `H-3`, we will choose `H-3`. So that number of nodes in entire tree is minimum, the number of node in **Right** (or Left) **subtree** should also be minimum. Thus **N<sub>H</sub>** is **also** a function of
   **N<sub>H-3</sub>**
6. Thus, to construct **Given Tree** of Height `H` such that **number of nodes** in the tree is **minimum**, we can have LEFT subtree as
   **Given Tree** of Height `H-1` such that **number of nodes** is **minimum** and can have RIGHT subtree as **Given Tree** of Height `H-3` such that **number of nodes** in it is also **minimum**, and can add one Root Node. Our tree will look like
   [image]

   Thus, we can form Recurrence Relation as

   **N<sub>H</sub> = N<sub>H-1</sub> + N<sub>H-3</sub> + 1**
   with base condition as
   **N<sub>0</sub>=1**
   **N<sub>1</sub>=2**
   **N<sub>2</sub>=3**
7. Now, this `Recurrence Relation` is Difficult to Solve. But courtesy to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4341827/963109), we can conclude that
   **N<sub>H</sub> > (√2)<sup>H</sup>**
8. Now, let `n` be the number of nodes in the **Given Tree** Then,

   **n ≥ N<sub>H</sub>

   n ≥ (√2)<sup>H</sup>

   log<sub>√2</sub>(n) ≥ H

   H ≤ log<sub>√2</sub>(n)

   H ≤ 2log<sub>2</sub>(n)**

Therefore, `H=O(log(n))`
Or `O(H) = O(log(n))`

Thus, **Worst Case Time Complexity** for **Searching** in this Given Tree will be `O(log(n))`

Hence, Proved Mathematically!